Is there a FUSE-based caching solution for selective prefetching from a remote filesystem?
I am working with a remote parallel file system (CephFS), mounted at /mnt/mycephfs/, which contains a large dataset of small files (200 GB+). My application trains on these files, but reading directly from /mnt/mycephfs/ is slow due to parallel file system contention and network latency.
I am looking for a FUSE-based solution that can:
1.  Take a list of files required by the application.
2.  Prefetch and cache these files into a local mount point (e.g., /mnt/prefetched/) without replicating the entire remote storage (as my local RAM and disk space are limited).
The desired behavior:
•   If a file (e.g., /mnt/mycephfs/file) is already cached at /mnt/prefetched/file, it should be served from the cache.
•   If not cached, the solution should fetch the file (along with other files from the prefetch list), cache it at /mnt/prefetched/, and then serve it from there.
Are there existing tools or frameworks that support this kind of selective caching and prefetching using FUSE?

"without replicating the entire remote storage" -- If there is enough free RAM for your particular set of files then vmtouch -l may be useful. This is not an answer because you explicitly asked for FUSE.

This question is similar to: How can I transparently cache any directory or mounted file system for reads and write back?. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

Although there are similarities, there are no prefetching component in the mentioned question @larsks

I don't think you need any FUSE for that (and anyways, FUSE is not very conductive to high-performance operations).
Instead, just mount your Ceph storage on /a, copy the paths you know you'll need to a local directory /b, and use OverlayFS, with /a as backing storage, and b/ as upper layer.
Reads will then go to a/ only if the file isn't present in b/.
But before I did that, I'd check whether just using your normal Ceph mount, and reading all relevant files (but not copying them anywhere, e.g., just doing cat /a/filename > /dev/null) is sufficient to make the kernel buffer their content in RAM, transparently.
